# How to addCuePoint in as3 with netstream?? i do not want to use FLVPlayback component

Tags: actionscript-3, flash-cs3, netstream

Is it possible to add cue points using as3 and I will not be using FLVPlayback component.

I want my flv or netstream object to call a function after 7 or 16 second or at any specified time during playing. I found addAsCuePoint the only way to do it.

If there is any other way to accomplish this task then I will not be using cue points..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using OSMF? You can easily add & listen to cue points.
http://www.opensourcemediaframework.com/